# box 1 contains 5000 bulbs of which 5% are defective. box 2 contains 4000 bulbs of which 3% are defective. two bulbs are draw without replacement from

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Q.box 1 contains 5000 bulbs of which 5% are defective. box 2 contains 4000 bulbs of which 3% are defective. two bulbs are draw without replacement from a randomly selected box. find the probability that both bulbs are defective.

Well I only know Bayes theorm and find it hard even to put in the formula
p(x=r)=nCrp^rq^n-r

Comment: This isn't a Bayes Theorem problem.  Presumably you are to suppose that you had an equal chance of choosing either of the two boxes, so condition on the choice you made.

Comment: Side note:  at least for a first pass I'd ignore the actual number of bulbs in the boxes.  Those numbers are high enough so that the two selections you make are nearly independent.  (N.B. it's not that much harder to do it exactly, but simplifying assumptions can provide a lot of insight).

Comment: It sounds like you need to apply the law of total probability.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the exact answer (and *presuming* that you will choose each box with equal probability, you need to apply the hypergeometric distribution and then apply the law of total probability, viz.

- Box $1$ has $5$% of $5000 = 250$ defectives,
  P($2$ defectives from box $1$) $= \frac{250}{5000}\cdot\frac{249}{4999} = A,\; (say)$
- Box $2$ has $3$% of $4000 = 120$ defectives,
  P($2$ defectives from box $2) = \frac{120}{4000}\cdot\frac{119}{3999}= B,\; (say)$
- Applying the law of total probability,
  required probability $= (1/2)(A+B)$

---

**Note**

The answer I get is $\large\frac{1127233}{666366700}, \approx 0.1691$% to $4$ dp

But in practical terms, an accuracy of this order is not needed, and we could well have simply computed it as $(\frac12)[(\frac5{100})^2+(\frac3{100})^2] = 0.17$%,  had not the question specifically mentioned **without replacement**